# Is there any way to put a string after a float in a list?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list : [1.0, 2.0, xD, 3.0, stack overflow is the best, 4]

And I want to put a string "x" only after the floats like so:

[1.0, x, 2.0, x, xD, 3.0, x, stack overflow is the best, 4]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: What do you mean by "after the floats"? Maybe you mean after *the last* float? Please provide more details and context about the task.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this and that's why I asked about it here so I really didn't try anything

Comment: I meant after every single float in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for? I think it can be achieved with an if statement.

[`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) is used here to check if the list element is a float. It returns a boolean value.

So if it's a float, I am appending that list element and then an `"x"` afterwards, if it's not a float, I am just appending that list element.

```
list1 = [1.0, 2.0, "xD", 3.0, "stack overflow is the best", 4]
list2 = []

for i in list1:
    list2.append(i)
    if isinstance(i, float):
        list2.append("x")

print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[1.0, 'x', 2.0, 'x', 'xD', 3.0, 'x', 'stack overflow is the best', 4]
```

(Thanks to [MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh) for a suggestion that simplified the code.)

Comment: You can move `list2.append(i)` out of the `if`-test and remove the `else` - it happens regardless of the value of `is_float`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler version of [DevLounge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429073/devlounge)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67655033/4518341) that uses an index instead of an iterator to modify the list in-place.

```
L = [1.0, 2.0, "xD", 3.0, "s", 4]

i = 0
while i < len(L):
    if isinstance(L[i], float):
        i += 1
        L.insert(i, 'x')
    i += 1

print(L)  # -> [1.0, 'x', 2.0, 'x', 'xD', 3.0, 'x', 's', 4]
```

Comment: much simpler indeed! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the list *in-place* you can do it this way:

```
def add_x_after_float(l: list) -> None:
    """ Inserts 'x' after each flot occurrence in the list 'l' """
    it = iter(l)
    position = 0
    while item := next(it, False):
        if isinstance(item, float):
            l.insert(position + 1, 'x')
            next(it, False)
            position += 1
        position += 1


demo_list = [1, 2, 3.0, 4, 'a', 'b', 5.1, 6, 'c']
add_x_after_float(demo_list)
print(demo_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3.0, 'x', 4, 'a', 'b', 5.1, 'x', 6, 'c']
```

The trick here is that I do not iterate on the list but on an iterator acting like a cursor which I can move by calling `next`, and it gives me full control on the position where I want to insert `x` and the item I want to consume.

To be honest, I did this for fun, after seeing your question. It might be an even easier way to do this *in-place*.

Comment: I posted [a simpler version of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67655128/4518341)